# Wildfly 10 persistence MySQL table not found

Tags: mysql, persistence, wildfly, inject

I have a REST service which access a MySQL database. I'm using Wildfly 10 and MySQL 5.7.12. I am trying to get the EntityManager as an injection and I get the following error when executing the `find` method for my Entity mapping the table content.

`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "MYTABLE" not found; SQL statement:`

In the RESTService class I have

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="myUnit") 
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

and my persistence.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="myUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytable" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

The issue is that if instead of using injection I retrieve the entity manager using the manual way everything works smothly.

```
EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myUnit");
EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
```

Could you give me some hints on how to use the PersistenceContext? the code is somehow cleaner and I prefer to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you 're getting the default datasource injected in your persistence Unit so I guess this depends on how the EntityManager is 'built'. One way to fix this is to create a datasource in WidFly and use it (through) its JNDI name in your persistence unit.
Feel free to report a bug http://issues.jboss.org/

Comment: Is there any way to create this datasource project wise? I don't want to modify the Wildfly configuration? For other things I've been able to jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up a RESOURCE_LOCAL persistence unit. You should configure it as such:

```
<persistence-unit transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

In order to use a resource local persistence unit you cannot inject EntityManager, only EntityManagerFactory.  You'll end up with a lot less plumbing if you switch to JTA datasource and let the server manage it.

If you absolutely don't want to edit standalone.xml, in WF8 anyway, you can drop yourdatasource-ds.xml file into your WEB-INF folder, or into the deployments directory alongside your .war file.  There was talk of removing this from WF though so I don't know if it works in 10.x.